# How do I get the list of the full indexed terms in an ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

Very simple question.
I have an ElasticSearch index with a text field. How do I get the list of all the words indexed for that field? Is there any simple method?

I'm working in python with `elasticsearch` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ⚠️ Warning

> fetching all indexed words of an index is expensive in terms of time
> and resources, especially if the number of unique terms is large. So
> please, be careful about it while using on production cluster.

### Solution

To be able to do so, the Elasticsearch first needs to load all that words into memory, which is disabled by default for text fields (see [FieldData mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) for more info).

Assuming that the field data is enable on your index, you can get the unique terms list, sorted by their frequence using below serach query:

```json
{
"size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "indexed_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "field_name",
                "size": 10000 (1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. size parameter controls the maximum number of unique terms to return.

unless enabling the fieldData, you will encounter such a below error:

> Text fields are not optimised for operations that require
> per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these
> operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field
> instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on your fields in order to
> load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can
> use significant memory.

### For a single document ...

If you only need to fetch such a list of indexed terms for a single document, you can simply use the [_termsvector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) API, while you don't need to enable field data anymore.